# Stack code from TDD book: trying to remove code duplicates

Tags: idris

Faced next problem while reading great Type Driven Development book and trying to implement some small modifications of tasks in it.

```
module Main

import Data.Vect

%default total

data Forever = More Forever

partial
forever : Forever
forever = More forever

data StackCmd : Type -> (inputHeight : Nat) -> (outputHeight : Nat) -> Type where
  Push : Integer -> StackCmd () height (S height)
  Pop : StackCmd Integer (S height) height
  Top : StackCmd Integer (S height) (S height)

  PutStr : String -> StackCmd () h h
  PutStrLn : String -> StackCmd () h h
  GetStr : StackCmd String h h

  Pure : a -> StackCmd a h h
  (>>=) : StackCmd a h1 h2 -> (a -> StackCmd b h2 h3) -> StackCmd b h1 h3


runStack : (stck : Vect inH Integer) -> StackCmd ty inH outH -> IO (ty, Vect outH Integer)
runStack stck (Push x) = pure ((), x :: stck)
runStack (x :: xs) Pop = pure (x, xs)
runStack (x :: xs) Top = pure (x, x :: xs)
runStack xs (PutStr str) = do putStr str; pure ((), xs)
runStack xs (PutStrLn str) = do putStrLn str; pure ((), xs)
runStack xs (GetStr) = do str <- getLine; pure (str, xs)
runStack stck (Pure x) = pure (x, stck)
runStack stck (x >>= f) = do (x', stck') <- runStack stck x 
                             runStack stck' (f x')

data StackIO : Nat -> Type where
  Do :    StackCmd a h1 h2 -> (a -> Inf (StackIO h2)) -> StackIO h1
  QuitCmd : (a : Nat) -> StackIO a

namespace StackDo
  (>>=) : StackCmd a h1 h2 -> (a -> Inf (StackIO h2)) -> StackIO h1
  (>>=) = Do

data Input : Type where
  INumber : Integer -> Input
  IAdd : Input
  IDuplicate : Input
  IDiscard : Input

parseInput : String -> Maybe Input
parseInput str = 
  case str of
    "" => Nothing
    "add" => Just IAdd
    "duplicte" => Just IDuplicate
    "discard" => Just IDiscard
    _      => if all isDigit $ unpack str then Just (INumber $ cast str) else Nothing


run : Forever -> Vect n Integer -> StackIO n -> IO ()
run _          _    (QuitCmd a) = pure ()
run (More far) stck (Do sa f)   = do (a', stck') <- runStack stck sa 
                                     run far stck' (f a')

biOp : (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> StackCmd String (S (S height)) (S height)
biOp op = do a <- Pop 
             b <- Pop
             let res = a `op` b
             Push res
             Pure $ show res

discardUnOp : StackCmd String (S height) height
discardUnOp = do v <- Pop
                 Pure $ "Discarded: " ++ show v

duplicateUnOp : StackCmd String (S height) (S (S height))
duplicateUnOp = do v <- Top
                   Push v
                   Pure $ "Duplicated: " ++ show v

mutual
  tryBiOp : String -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> StackIO hin
  tryBiOp _      op {hin=S (S k)} = do res <- biOp op
                                       PutStrLn res
                                       stackCalc
  tryBiOp opName _                = do PutStrLn $
                                         "Unable to execute operation " ++ opName ++ ": fewer then two items on stack."
                                       stackCalc

  tryUnOp : Show a => String -> StackCmd a hIn hOut -> StackIO hIn
  tryUnOp _ op   {hIn=S h} = do res <- op
                                PutStrLn $ show res
                                stackCalc
  tryUnOp opName _         = do PutStrLn $ 
                                  "Unable to execute " ++ opName ++ " operation: no elements on stack."
                                stackCalc

  stackCalc : StackIO height
  stackCalc = do PutStr "> "
                 inp <- GetStr
                 case parseInput inp of
                   Nothing => do PutStrLn "invalid input"; stackCalc
                   (Just (INumber x)) => do Push x; stackCalc
                   (Just IAdd) => tryBiOp "add" (+)
                   (Just IDuplicate) => ?holedup
                   (Just IDiscard) => ?holedisc -- tryUnOp "discard" discardUnOp

partial
main : IO ()
main = run forever [] stackCalc
```

Code given above is mostly from TDD book. Sorry that its a bit long: it can be compiled. The code is rather straightforward: this is a stack implemented above vector. Then, user can type numbers in command prompt (one per line) and program pushes the numbers on stack. User is also able to call operations, i.e. `add`. `add` pops two elements from stack, adds them and pushes the result back on stack. So, `add` requires at least two numbers to be on stack when it is called.

Please take a look on `tryBiOp` function. It takes an `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` (i.e. `(+)` or `(-)`) operation as it's argument and returns sequence of `StackCmd` operations which implements needed action. As a result programmer can write `(Just IAdd) => tryBiOp "add" (+)` inside `stackCalc`. This is very close to what I would like to have.

*Question.* Next thing I would like to do is very the same wrapper (it named `tryUnOp`) for operations which require one element on stack. And since these operations are not on integers, but on a stack itself (i.e. "duplicate top of stack" or "discard top element") I would like to pass to wrapper the sequence of `StackCmd` operations instead of `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`. So, what I would like to gain is

```
(Just IDuplicate) => tryUnOp "duplicate" $ 
                       (do v <- Top
                           Push v
                           Pure $ "Duplicated: " ++ show v)
```

*Problem.* If you uncomment code in string `(Just IDiscard) => ?holedisc -- tryUnOp "discard" discardUnOp` (and remove hole), you will see that code can not be compiled. As I see problem is that when I call `tryUnOp "discard" discardUnOp` Idris can see that `tryUnOp`'s `hIn` must be of form (S k) because it follows from `discardUnOp`'s type. But `stackCalc` does not provide such guarantee.

*Working solution.* It works, but it is essentially the same thing for unary operation as for binary. So, it is not exactly what I would like to have. There is a function which converts name of operation to sequence of stack commands:

```
data UnaryOperation : Type where
  UODup : UnaryOperation
  UODisc : UnaryOperation

UnaryOpOutHeight : UnaryOperation -> Nat -> Nat
UnaryOpOutHeight UODup inheightBase = S (S inheightBase)
UnaryOpOutHeight UODisc inheightBase = inheightBase

unaryStackCmd : (op: UnaryOperation) -> StackCmd String (S h) (UnaryOpOutHeight op h)
unaryStackCmd UODup = duplicateUnOp
unaryStackCmd UODisc = discardUnOp

mutual
  tryUnOp' : String -> UnaryOperation -> StackIO height
  tryUnOp' _      op {height=S h} = do res <- unaryStackCmd op
                                       PutStrLn res
                                       stackCalc
  tryUnOp' opName _            = do PutStrLn $
                                      "Unable to execute " ++ opName ++ " operation: no elements on stack."
                                    stackCalc
```

**Any ideas / comments are wellcome!!!**

Comment: The root of your problem is that you have different branches in `stackCalc` return different stack sizes, and so the type of the branches themselves are different (in the index of `StackIO`).

Comment: @Cactus, thank you for comment. I think I understand it in the same way as you've said. But I do not have enough experience with Idris to solve it or to understand it is impossible to write it in needed form.